# Calculating Newton Form of Interpolating Polynomial

Tags: numerical-methods, interpolation

For the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$, I am trying to calculate the Newton form of the interpolating polynomial for the points $x_0=2$, $x_1=3$ and $x_2=4$.

I understand that the Newton form of the interpolating polynomial is given by
$P_2(x) = f(x_0)+f[x_0,x_1](x-x_0)+f[x_0,x_1, x_2](x-x_0)(x-x_1),$

where

$f[x_0,x_1] = \frac{f(x_1)-f(x_0)}{x_1-x_0}$

and

$f[x_0,x_1, x_2] = \frac{f(x_0)}{(x_0-x_1)(x_1-x_2)}+\frac{f(x_1)}{(x_1-x_2)(x_1-x_2)}+\frac{f(x_2)}{(x_2-x_0)(x_2-x_1)}$,

however when I plug in the given values and simplify I keep getting the wrong answer. Could someone please verify that my formulas are correct? Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a tabular method that is rather nice for hand calculations. It is in *Numerical Analysis* by Timothy Sauer, and can probably be found online as well. You might want to try to find it.

Comment: See [Neville's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neville%27s_algorithm).

Comment: Huh, I never knew the name, but that is exactly what I meant.

Comment: The way you write $f[x_0,x_1,x_2]$ is not correct. The denominator of the first term is $(x_0-x_1)(x_0-x_2)$ and  that of the second is $(x_1-x_0)(x_1-x_2).$